# Less CSS - reverse parent of parent

Tags: css, less, selector, parent

Is it possible in Less CSS to get the parent of the parent?

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

```
#parent1 {
  #parent2 {
    #grandparent & & {
      /* stuff */
    }
  }
}
```

to equate to:

```
#grandparent #parent1 #parent2 { /* stuff */ }
```

Thoughts?

Comment: No it isn't. You'll have to duplicate your code up the tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pasted your code here: http://less2css.org/

Instead of:

```
#parent1 {
  #parent2 {
    #grandparent & & {
      /* stuff */
    }
  }
}
```

I tried

```
#parent1 {
  #parent2 {
    #grandparent & {
      /* stuff */
    }
  }
}
```

And that equates to:
`#grandparent #parent1 #parent2 { /* stuff */ }`

Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: Oh, so it's going all the way up the tree?  I would have thought that would equate to:  #parent1 #grandparent #parent 2 { ... }

Comment: If you do this `&#grandparent {` then it will go up by one, but if you `#grandparent &` that goes all the way up. I think... lol.

Comment: The "position" of the `&` has no bearing on how many levels up it goes. It always goes all levels. I give a brief explanation of it at the beginning of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472776/referencing-parent-with-multiple-levels-of-nesting-in-less/14476912#14476912), and the discussion with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537260/less-css-abusing-the-operator-when-nesting/11544805#11544805) might be useful also.

Comment: @ScottS Thank you for clarifying that, I've read the beginning part of the answer you've linked. I'm going to read rest once I wrote this comment. I'm sorry MrA for giving you the wrong information, my comment above is completely false. Thanks again ScottS.