# Target immediate parent in LESS from within nested classes

Tags: css, less

So I have a bunch of nested classes. I'd like to target the IMMEDIATE parent from deep within the nest. So for example, I have:

```
.navbar {
   ul {
      li {
         a {
            .ACTIVE & {
              background: red;
            }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

The above results in:

```
.ACTIVE .navbar ul li a {
   background: red;
}
```

But what I am trying to achieve is:

```
.navbar ul li.ACTIVE a {
   background: red;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you can do that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519931/less-css-accessing-classes-further-up-the-dom-tree-from-within-a-nested-class?rq=1

Comment: ..or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472776/referencing-parent-with-multiple-levels-of-nesting-in-less?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Do get to that path using LESS, you'd do something like

```
.navbar {
   & > ul {
      & > li {
         & > a {
            &.active {
              background: red;
            }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

This will result the following selector:

```
.navbar > ul > li > a.active { background: red; }
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, totally missed the most important part.... So, to get what you're trying to achieve :

```
.navbar {
    ul {
       li {
         &.ACTIVE{
           a {
              background: red;
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to move up from within the a tag.

Comment: @user2726041 I have edited my answer multiple time. Please make sure I tried my last attempt. Because I wasn't focused. Sorry

Comment: Thanks Alon, yes I'm seeing the latest answer. But I'm looking to target the LI from within the A.